# Como especifico valor maximo a un generador de numeros aleatorios en un arreglo?

Tags: c#, array, random

Necesito especificarle un valor minimo y maximo a un arreglo usando el metodo .NextBytes().

```
        Random aleatorio = new Random();
        byte[] arreglo = new byte[4];
        aleatorio.NextBytes(arreglo);

        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(arreglo[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

¡Buenas tardes! ¿Por qué necesitas hacerlo únicamente con el método .NextBytes?

Existe también Next (int minValue, int maxValue); en la clase Random que te permite introducir un intervalo. Aquí te dejo tu ejemplo modificado:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         Random aleatorio = new Random();       
         int minvalue = 0, maxvalue = 10;
         for (int i = 0; i < maxvalue ; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(aleatorio.Next(minvalue , maxvalue));
         }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, ¡un saludo!